# Advice on searching with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search, search-engine

Basically, I got the same problem as this guy but I also need relevancy: [PHP 'smart' search engine to search Mysql tables advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878899/php-smart-search-engine-to-search-mysql-tables-advice)

But, I can't use Sphinx or Lucene (shared hosting)...

I can use LIKE but that has not relevancy so does anyone know a good PHP class that does create relevancy?

So I need something that fits this bill:

- Result relevancy value
- Match part of words, i.e. "LIKE %searchterm%"
- Search multiple database columns
- Can't use things like Sphinx or Lucene, no supported by my shared hosting...

I'm using the CakePHP framework.

Comment: On a side note, I'd remark that you can have a very reasonable VPS for dirt cheap nowadays, so if you're up for minor administration / monitoring of your server, you can have any package you like.

Comment: At the moment that is out of the question. Really all I need is a script that creates relevancy values alongside a LIKE search. There has to be a simple PHP class someone created for this purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using mysql's full-text search in boolean mode. I also append the * operators to each search term.

user input: 
**tom jones**

resulting query:
**match(name,description) against('tom* jones* IN BOOLEAN MODE');**

Thanks for everyone's help.

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested in my presentation [Practical Full Text Search in MySQL](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

I compare performance of several solutions:

- `LIKE` predicates
- MyISAM `FULLTEXT` indexes
- Sphinx Search
- Lucene (or Solr)
- Google Custom Search Engine
- Inverted indexes

If you have no opportunity to install a dedicated search engine, I'd recommend using FULLTEXT or Google CSE.

Using `LIKE` predicates is pretty clearly the worst choice.

---

I have tried Zend_Search_Lucene, the pure-PHP clone of Apache Lucene, but the PHP version is much too slow at indexing.  See my answer to [Can I predict how large my Zend Framework index will be? (and some quick Q:s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943300/can-i-predict-how-large-my-zend-framework-index-will-be-and-some-quick-qs/1943486#1943486)

Zend_Search_Lucene also hasn't maintained compatibility with new versions of the Apache Lucene index file format.  See [Using Solr and Zends Lucene port together…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668279/using-solr-and-zends-lucene-port-together/2677657#2677657)

Comment: Thanks Bill, but I really just need something simple that just gives some sort of relevancy to LIKE %% results, the other solutions out of the question atm unfortunatly

Comment: FULLTEXT indexes are too complex?  *Really?*

Comment: No, what I meant by simple is a something in the form of a class instead of a full-blow plugin like Sphinx, Solr... I'm already using mysql's fulltext searh, which has relevancy only when not in boolean mode

Comment: So why not use fulltext searches then?  The typical pattern is `SELECT MATCH... AS relevance FROM ... WHERE MATCH...IN BOOLEAN MODE ORDER BY relevance` so you use boolean to find matching rows, and non-boolean to make a relevance column you can sort by.

Comment: Because non boolean returns a different result that in boolean?? That makes the relevance irrelevant ;)

Comment: Okay, but `LIKE` doesn't return relevance, it only returns true/false.  Your solution in MySQL to return relevance is FULLTEXT in non-boolean mode.  Sorry I can't offer anything different.

Answer (score 1):

[Zend_Search_Lucene](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.search.lucene.html) is an implementation of Lucene in pure PHP.  I use it on a shared hosting website I run.